# iPhone: Is it possible to poll whether the camera is active or not?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, camera

We're creating a photo app that lets the user take a number of photos in series. For some reason the camera seems to die with no obvious trigger. This typically appears to happen if the camera is running and the device is idle (screensaver/locking) or if the main iPhone button is pressed and the app is minimized. So we need to find a way to check if the camera is still running or not. Can this be polled somehow? Have someone experienced a similar issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you can get a camera view on self.view you can say that camera is active or present.. here is how you can check if camera view is available or not -

```
UIView *cameraView = [self findCamControlsLayerView:self.view];
if (cameraView)
// camera is present
else
// camera is not present




// Find the view that contains the camera controls (buttons)
- (UIView*)findCamControlsLayerView:(UIView*)view {

Class cl = [view class];
NSString *desc = [cl description];
if ([desc compare:@"PLCropOverlay"] == NSOrderedSame)
return view;

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [view.subviews count]; i++)
{
UIView *subView = [view.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
subView = [self findCamControlsLayerView:subView];
if (subView)
return subView;
}

return nil;
}
```